# Cannot access props sent from toggle in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering this list like so

```
const roomsAttached = this.state.rooms_attached.map((item, index) => (
<View key={index}>
    <Text>{index}</Text>
    <Switch
    thumbColor='#eee'
    onValueChange={(value, index) => this.losToggle(value, index)}
    value={item.room_attached_los}
    />
</View>
))
```

I simply cannot access the index from the list item, I have always used a similar syntax and it worked out the box now all I am getting is undefined.

```
losToggle (los, index) {
    console.log('index :', index)
    console.log('LOS: ' + los)
}
```

Can please someone assist? I also tried `item`, same issue

Comment: Study about scopes and closures and related topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the passed callback function definition in `onValueChange`prop, to this, will works:

```js
onValueChange={value => this.losToggle(value, index)}
```